# Other way than splitting with coma to store in a database?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I started created a database with postgresql and I am currently facing a problem when I want to copy the data from my csv file to my database

Here is my code:

```
connexion = psycopg2.connect(dbname= "db_test" , user = "postgres", password ="passepasse" )
connexion.autocommit = True
cursor = connexion.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE vocabulary(
    fname integer PRIMARY KEY,
    label text,
    mids text
    )""")

with open (r'C:\mypathtocsvfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip the header row
    cursor.copy_from(f, 'vocabulary', sep=',')
    
connexion.commit()
```

I asked to allocate 4 column to store my csv data, the problem is that datas in my csv are stored like this:

```
fname,labels,mids,split
64760,"Electric_guitar,Guitar,Plucked_string_instrument,Musical_instrument,Music","/m/02sgy,/m/0342h,/m/0fx80y,/m/04szw,/m/04rlf",train
16399,"Electric_guitar,Guitar,Plucked_string_instrument,Musical_instrument,Music","/m/02sgy,/m/0342h,/m/0fx80y,/m/04szw,/m/04rlf",train
...
```

There is comas inside my columns `label` and `mids`, thats why i get the following error:

```
BadCopyFileFormat: ERROR: additional data after the last expected column
```

Which alternativ should I use to copy data from this csv file?

ty

Comment: You can try to change the separator from your CSV so it won't conflict with the commas in the text. Such as ';'.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is small, then the easiest way is to open the file in LibreOffice and save the file with a new separetor.  I usually use ^.  If the file is large, write a script to replace ," and "," on ^" and "^", respectively.

Comment: yes it's a large file, thank you for the tips, i'll try this

Answer (score 0):

COPY supports csv as a format, which already does what you want.  But to access it via psycopg2, I think you will need to use copy_expert rather than copy_from.

```
cursor.copy_expert('copy vocabulary from stdin with csv', f)
```